# VB syntax (named arguments)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VB script with a line that looks like this:

```
Set startCell = referenceCell.EntireColumn.Find(tmp).offset(0,columnOffset)
```

But I want to specify the `find` (to search exactly for the given word in each column) to something like:

```
Set startCell = referenceCell.EntireColumn.Find(tmp, lookat:=xlWhole).offset(0,columnOffset)
```

all according to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx

But that gives me a syntax error. (I hate VB)

I have also tried

```
Set tmp = "Precondition" & preconditionNumber
Set startCell = ReferenceCell.EntireColumn.Find(what:=tmp,lookat:=xlWhole).offset(0,columnOffset)
```

and even

```
Set startCell = ReferenceCell.EntireColumn.Find(what:=tmp).offset(0,columnOffset)
```

none of which works. 
How should I call the `Find` function to get a `Whole Word`-Search?
The variable declaration looks like this:

```
Dim startCell

for preconditionNumber = 0 to 15 
      Set startCell = Nothing 
      tmp = "Precondition" & preconditionNumber 
      Set startCell = referenceCell.EntireColumn.Find(tmp).offset(0,columnOffset)
      ...
```

Here is the exact syntax error message.
[image]

Comment: What type is `tmp`? If it's a `String` or a `Variant` you should use `Let`; `Set` is for objects. What type is startCell declared? It should be as `Excel.Range`.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no clue. The error message says that it expects at char 57 a right parenthesis, but that's in the middle of an identifier (if you use 4-spaces tabs). It makes no sense... If anything else passes through my mind though, I'll let you know.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean! Damn VBA

Comment: lol VBScript you mean not VBA? or both... hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim ReferenceCell As Range, rCol As Range, tmp As String
    Dim GotIt As Range, MoveOver As Range, columnOffset As Long

    Set ReferenceCell = Range("B9")
    Set rCol = ReferenceCell.EntireColumn.Cells
    tmp = "happiness"
    columnOffset = 2

    Set GotIt = rCol.Find(what:=tmp, after:=rCol(1), lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set MoveOver = GotIt.Offset(0, columnOffset)
    MoveOver.Select
End Sub
```

Fixing VBA hatred is even easier, just repeat:

*VBA is my friend.*

30 times every morning

Comment: _VBA is my friend.*_ The psychological community calls this Stockholm syndrome. :D

Comment: I am sure if I understood VBA I would be amazed by this :) but this is one huge file, without any functions that is run from the top to the button I don't even dare to change anything other than the actual call to the Find-function.

Comment: @theAlse  ...........it is important to replace the **single** *Find()* statement with a series of statements .........this will allow us to see exactly which part of the *Find()* line is failing!